# How to change input placeholder color javascript onmouseover, change placeholder value onmouseover?

Tags: placeholder

1) I would change the input placeholder color in some condition using javascript (not CSS if it will change the placeholder color forever)
2) And I want that the placeholder change to another placeholder onmouseover the input box.
I got this function:

```
if(email.value==''){
email.style.borderColor = "#FF0000";
email.setAttribute('placeholder',"Plea… fill this required field");
//code for changing the placeholder color
//code for changing the placeholder onmouseover
}
```

1) The placeholder color for me usually is "#C9C9C9" I want to change it to another color by this code.
2) I want the placeholder text to change to any other text onmouseover.
I will be thankful for the one who will give me the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Look with this post's answer to do it in CSS : [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Then, you can include the **CSS** rule with **javascript**.

And you just have to use pseudo-class `:hover` for the *mouseover*.

Just like that :

**CSS**

```
input.formInvalid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("yourElementId").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid to your element
```

Comment: There is a cleaner way to add the class:
document.getElementById("yourElementId").classList.add(" formInvalid");

Comment: such an elegant solution but for some reason it isn't working for me :/